# Responsive Navigation - flexbox dropdowns causing overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently doing a quick website. Got navigation styled and working correctly, however I implemented a drop down as a nav item. This causes three problems I can't quite seem to fix:

1. On the navigation toggle, content overlaps with each other.
2. On the nav toggle, the navigation makes you scroll, even through there
   is room to expand the dropdown on desktop screens the hover.
3. On desktop screens the nav item causes the drop to happen within the           header with a scroll bar.

Been stuck on this for a while any assistance would be appreciated.

```js
function NavToggle() {
  var tn = document.getElementById("nav-bar")
  if (tn.style.display === "none") {
    tn.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    tn.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header and Navigation */

header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #222;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.title-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 10px;
}


/* menu base styles */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  height: 50px;
}

.title-wrapper>a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  color: #999;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Menu Toggle Styling */

.menu-toggle {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 15px 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-toggle-button {
  padding: inherit;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 930px) {
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  /* Header Content */
  .header-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-wrapper {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .header-title {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #nav-bar {
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  a {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav-dropdown:hover>.nav-dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="nav-wrapper header-container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="title-wrapper">
        <a>Chemical Finger Print Analysis</a>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
          <span id="menu-toggle-button" onclick="NavToggle()">&#9776;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-dropdown"><a href="#" class="a-tag header-a">Account</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Order History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wishlist</a></li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>





</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the first two issues, you have to set the `display` of `.nav-dropdown` to `inline-block`:

```
.nav-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

To fix the third issue, you have to set the `overflow` of the header to `visible`, since you have set it to `auto` which generates scroll bars if the content overflows.

```
.header-container {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

This is a working example (without fixing any other issues):

```js
function NavToggle() {
  var tn = document.getElementById("nav-bar")
  if (tn.style.display === "none") {
    tn.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    tn.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header and Navigation */

header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #222;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.title-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 10px;
}


/* menu base styles */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  height: 50px;
}

.title-wrapper>a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  color: #999;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Menu Toggle Styling */

.menu-toggle {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 15px 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-toggle-button {
  padding: inherit;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 930px) {
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #222;
  }
  /* Header Content */
  .header-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-wrapper {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .header-title {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #nav-bar {
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  a {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav-dropdown:hover>.nav-dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="nav-wrapper header-container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="title-wrapper">
        <a>Chemical Finger Print Analysis</a>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
          <span id="menu-toggle-button" onclick="NavToggle()">&#9776;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-dropdown"><a href="#" class="a-tag header-a">Account</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Order History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wishlist</a></li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>





</body>
```

Or see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/savsc92a/) fiddle.

Comment: That inline block fixed the problem for that, thank you